# Customize md-tab in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I got some problem to style md-tab component in Angular 2. I know that Angular 2 Materials is still in development now but I want to know if there is a way to customize that and for example remove bottom-radius.
Here is a code of that:

```
<md-card>
    <md-tab-group [selectedIndex]="1">
      <md-tab>
        <template md-tab-label>
          MY FILES
        </template>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab>
        <template md-tab-label>
          ALL FILES
        </template>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab>
        <template md-tab-label>
          MY INTERESTS
        </template>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Inspect your element, see the related class, and override it with your own CSS code.

Comment: I was trying this kind of solution but when I insert some class in tags "md-tabs" and "template" then after compilation, I do not have these classes inserted in generated code

Comment: also trying styling classes which this compiled code already have

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular2 but I faced this problem in Angular1. It's strange that your classes get deleted ... Maybe try to override the class used by angular ?

Comment: ok, after searching in inspect mode I know why my styling code won't work when I do it on generated classes:

this is generated css from my scss code (I have written class e.q .md-tab-header)
.md-tab-header[_ngcontent-mfl-3] {
  background-color: black !important; }

In generated html I have classes named 
.md-tab-header and .md-tab-header[_ngcontent-mfl-5] which contain all the styling stuff. That's why my styling code won't work.

But still I do not how to solve this problem

Comment: Can't you apply your own CSS now that you know where the problem comes from ?

Comment: Ok I know. This is because improvements which angular 2 provides. My <md-card> code is in other component which I was styling and in that place I wanted style <md-card>. Angular 2 compiling code in that way that I can not get access to style child component in parent component. Everything is here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html .

Answer (score 1):

In the component where you are using material components, add your css code with prefix `/deep/` like this:-

```
/deep/ .mat-tab-label{
        min-width: 25px !important;
        padding: 5px;
}
```

For knowing class name of desired element, go developer tools of respective browser, and select the element of which you want to change the `border-radius`. Now after getting the class name, do something like this:-

```
/deep/ .mat-class-name{
    border-radius:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know. This is because improvements which angular 2 provides. My  code is in other component which I was styling and in that place I wanted style . Angular 2 compiling code in that way that I can not get access to style child component in parent component. Everything is here: angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html .